# Does the zeroth and 100-percentile exist and do the minimum and maximum of the data belong in those respective sets?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, quantiles

Does the zeroth and 100-percentile exist and do the minimum and maximum of a set of data belong in those respective sets?

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430391/are-there-99-percentiles-or-100-percentiles-and-are-they-groups-of-numbers-or/430464#430464

Comment: A percentile is, by definition, a *number,* not a set.

Comment: zeroth percentile is the minimum, yes, and 100-percentile is the maximum